# How do I fingerprint images?

Tags: image, fingerprint

I saw this command for imagemagick which is cool

```
compare -metric RMSE first.png second.png NULL:
```

I tried it and two similar images (however not a modification of each other) scored <15% difference. But if I wanted to find images that are similar I cant really scan them against each image with 1M images, it would just be too consuming. Is there a way to fingerprint the images instead (edge fingerprints maybe? edge+color?) and store a 1-4k bytes and use that data to compare how close they are instead?

Comment: One possible duplicate (or very related): [OpenCV / SURF How to generate a image hash / fingerprint / signature out of the descriptors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146542/opencv-surf-how-to-generate-a-image-hash-fingerprint-signature-out-of-the)

Comment: Another one: [Image fingerprint to compare similarity of many images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596262/image-fingerprint-to-compare-similarity-of-many-images)

Comment: And another one: [Near-Duplicate Image Detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034900/near-duplicate-image-detection/)