# Objects recognition in images

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, face-detection, object-detection

Suppose I have an grayscale image this:- {first image}
and i want to check whether this image exists in this one below:-{second}

without any third party library


 first image
  [image: first image]  
second
  [image: second]
 
I thought of using `Getpixel()` to get all the black pixels and check if the pattern matches

Sorry for my English

Comment: Have a look at Image convolution and template Matching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching . The easiest way would be to shift the first image through the second one and sum up the multiplied matching values. Store the sum value for each shifted step with its coordinates and when finished you look for the maximum to get the best match coordinates.

Comment: If the image is going to be a chunk of the big one, not a "similar" one, but a literal cutted part, then you should not do convolution and template matching, but image integrals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663764/determine-if-an-image-exists-within-a-larger-image-and-if-so-find-it-using-py

Comment: That's what you wanna do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262832/detect-the-location-of-an-image-within-a-larger-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105375/how-to-detect-occurrencies-of-a-small-image-in-a-larger-image