# Detect presence of image within (possibly) another image

Tags: c#

Basically for example, in an application there's a randomized, standard 3x3 number pad populated by the numbers 0-9 non-repeating with 10th number in the bottom middle position.  What I want to do is determine the location of each digit in the number pad in its entirety or only 4, 6, and 8 for example.

The positions of each number cannot be determined through memory (as a rule) so my first thought was template matching.  The number pad is always in the same format and in the same location so this would in theory be alright.

I have searched around here briefly and found a couple of things

1) OCR is a viable solution to my problem as well, however, OCR may be 'overkill' for my needs and without proceeding further as of yet, I don't know how complex or simple OCR is to implement.

2) Down and dirty bruteforce approach sliding templates and doing a similarity threshhold which I assume would be anything but efficient as found here:

[Detect the location of an image within a larger image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262832/detect-the-location-of-an-image-within-a-larger-image)

Aside from reading memory, are OCR, template matching, and bruteforcing the only solutions to this?

Comment: This is hard to imagine. First thought: Arent the numers always in the same order? Second thought: Why *number cannot be determined through memory* (what ever that means)?

Comment: For my specific case the positions of each number in the number pad will be randomized.  In the application, each number is a button so I assume the value of each button can be read accessed in memory removing the need to analyze the screen.