# How to Detect which object is present in image.?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have given a task to create an application, in which the image was given and i have to detect which object (out of list of finite objects) is present in that image..
Only one object is present in one image or no object in image.
the application should able to identify the object if present(any of the listed objects) 
It would also be suffice if application(program) can calculate that what is probability that particular object is present in image (from the list of objects).

Can anyone suggest how to approach this problem ? opencv ?

Actually the task was to identify the logo(of some company like coke, pepsi, dell etc) from the image(if present any from the list of logos(which is finite say 100))

How can i do this project ? please help.!!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2074956/176769

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways of doing that but the one I like the most is building a feature set for each object and then match it in the image.

You can use [SIFT](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/feature_detection.html#sift) for building the keypoints vector for each object. By aplying SIFT to each picture yo will get a set of descriptors for each picture (say picture, object,...).

When you get the image you want to process, use [FAST](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_feature_detection_and_description.html) for detecting points, and do [cvMatchTemplate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/object_detection.html)() for each different set of descriptors. The one with highest probability will tell you which objected you detected. If all probabilities are too low, then you probably don't have any object on the image.

This is just one approach I like, but it is quite state-of-the-art, precise, fast.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you [googling](http://www.google.com) and reading on the subject before trying to do stuff. 
You want to perform [object recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_object_recognition), or logo recognition. There are already [SO questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074956/logo-recognition-in-images).

[Here is a starting point for Opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/object_recognition.html)

The whole process took me half a minute to search for. Perhaps this is what you should start searching for