# Can Tensorflow Object Detect With a Small Data Set?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am hoping that TensorFlow can turn this input, to this output.

Input: A floorplan PNG, and 1 - 5 images of a symbol

Output: The same floorplan, but with all matching symbols highlighted

I can do the hard work of figuring out HOW to do it, but I don't want to waste 2 weeks just to figure out it wouldn't be possible. I know I'd need to train it with multiple images, but I won't have more than 5 examples of a given symbol.

Does TensorFlow have these capabilities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use tensorflow to create a machine learning algorithm to do that for you, but I would bet that is not how you want to do this. First off, in order to do this in tensorflow, you would need to manually create a large number of training samples and spend a significant amount of time figuring out how to define the network and train it. Sure, you could do it, but I definitely wouldn't advise it.

If you have a specific set of symbols that you want to highlight, it would probably be better to use opencv to find and highlight the symbols. For example, in opencv, you could use [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) to find a specific symbol in the floor plan and then highlight them by modifying pixel color.

Comment: I know "recommendations" aren't encouraged here, but are there other algorithms worth implementing, to compare performance against the Template Matching algorithm?

Comment: I do not know anything specific personally, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319867/what-is-the-best-method-to-template-match-a-image-with-noise) seems to address the issue to some extent. To be fair, you could train a few basic models in tensorflow(or any other machine learning library) and see how they do. They might end up having better performance.

Comment: _Template matching_ wouldn't world well in this context as it will not be able to recognize a (affine) transformed version of a given symbol. I recommend you to have a look at [**Feature Matching**](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) instead.

Comment: @ElouarnLaine in plain simple binary image there is no features