# Find if apple logo is present in target image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, boofcv

I need to find if the small image (pattern of a logo) is in a target image (bigger)?

i have tried the templateMatching - it works only when the exact part of the image is given to search for in the target image

How to find if apple logo is present in target image

How do i handle this?

Comment: Have a look on Haar or LBP features

Comment: [Algorithm improvement for Coca-Cola can shape recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10168686/2545927) might give you some ideas...

Comment: But also [Logo recognition in images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074956/logo-recognition-in-images) (see in particular the *bundle min-Hashing* approach).

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible ways. You can use:

- Surf(Speeded-Up Robust Features) detection
- Haar-like or LBP features ( <- you need some test images)

or take a look at this tutorial-> [Features2D+Homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use rescale of image. For example resize the image with 1.1 (increase size), or different scale for 3, 4 or more times, try, and with 0.9 (decrease size) for same. Now you can found the logo in a different dimensions in your image.

Resize: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize