# How to detect and recognize a specific object in an image

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I want to detect Or recognize a specific object in an image. **First of all** say what I have done. I tried to detect a LOGO **e.g** Google LOGO, I have the original image of the LOGO, but in the images which I am going to process are taken with different cameras from different angle and from different distance and from different screens (wide screen like cinema).

I am using OpenCV 3 to check whether this LOGO is in these images, I have tried the OpenCV SURF, SIFT etc functions and also tried NORM_L2 algorithm, which compares two images and template matching and also used SVM (it was so slow and not correct detection) and some other OpenCV functions, **but** no one was good to use. **Then** I did my own algorithm which is working better than the above functions, but also cannot satisfy the requirements.

**Now** my question is: Is there any better way to detect the specific object in an image? For example: what should I do at the first and second... steps?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370006/5008845) for some info

Comment: Could you share your algorithm with us? perhaps a stackoverflow user could improve that as per your requirements.